# Pandas - Resample/GroupBy DateTime Index and perform calculations

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I will try my best to explain what I need help with. I have the following df (thousands if not millions of rows) with a datetime index like the sample below:

```
INDEX                   COL A       COL B
2018-05-07 21:53:13.731 0.365127    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:16.201 0.666127    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:18.038 0.143104    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:18.243 0.025643    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:18.265 0.640484    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:18.906 -0.100000   9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:19.829 0.559516    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:19.846 0.100000    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:19.870 0.006560    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:20.734 0.666076    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:20.775 0.666076    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:28.607 0.100000    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:28.610 0.041991    9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:29.283 -0.053518   9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:47.322 -0.046302   9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:49.182 0.100000    9391.800000
```

What I would like to do is group the rows in 5 second intervals and perform (sometimes complex) calculations on each 5 second interval/subset.

Let's say for example I want to calculate the percentage of positive vs negative values in column A within each 5 second block.

`2018-05-07 21:53:10` to `2018-05-07 21:53:15` only contains one row and column A is a positive so I would create a new column C with `100%`.

Similarly `2018-05-07 21:53:15` to `2018-05-07 21:53:20` has 8 rows in column A, 7 which are positive and 1 of which is negative. So column C would be `87.5%`.

I would post sample code but I'm really unsure the best way to do this. A sample output (new df) may be something like the below with COL D being simply the minimum number in COL B for that 5 second grouping:

```
INDEX               COL C     COL D (MIN)
2018-05-07 21:53:10 100%     9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:15 12.5%    9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:20 100%     9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:25 66.7%    9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:30 nan      nan
2018-05-07 21:53:35 nan      nan
2018-05-07 21:53:40 nan      nan
2018-05-07 21:53:45 100%     9391.793421
```

**Please keep in mind I want to do many different calculations over each grouping.** So using built-in `.sum()`, `.mean()`, `.agg()` etc will not suffice for more complex calculations.

Appreciate any help and am happy to clarify the question if needed.

Comment: I am a bit confused with first column, can you explain more?

Comment: I believe you are referencing the wrong columns in your description.  Column B is _always_ positive.  In addition, for pos vs neg, I would think the correct value would be 87.5% (7/8) in your second example instead of 12.5%.

Comment: Alexander has it, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need for percentage of positive values need mean of values `>0`:

```
df = df.resample('5S').agg({'COL A': lambda x: (x > 0).mean() * 100, 'COL B': 'min'})
print (df)
                          COL A        COL B
INDEX                                       
2018-05-07 21:53:10  100.000000  9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:15   87.500000  9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:20  100.000000  9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:25   66.666667  9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:30         NaN          NaN
2018-05-07 21:53:35         NaN          NaN
2018-05-07 21:53:40         NaN          NaN
2018-05-07 21:53:45   50.000000  9391.793421
```

and for percentage of negative values need mean of `<0`:

```
df = df.resample('5S').agg({'COL A': lambda x: (x < 0).mean() * 100, 'COL B': 'min'})
print (df)
                         COL A        COL B
INDEX                                      
2018-05-07 21:53:10   0.000000  9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:15  12.500000  9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:20   0.000000  9391.800000
2018-05-07 21:53:25  33.333333  9391.793421
2018-05-07 21:53:30        NaN          NaN
2018-05-07 21:53:35        NaN          NaN
2018-05-07 21:53:40        NaN          NaN
2018-05-07 21:53:45  50.000000  9391.793421
```

As @Alexander pointed `0`  is neither positive nor negative. So the best is remove it before count:

```
df = df.resample('5S').agg({'COL A': lambda x: (x[x.ne(0)] > 0).mean() * 100, 'COL B': 'min'})
```

Comment: `lambda x: x.ne(0).mean() * 100`? (otherwise you treat values of zero as positive)

Comment: @Alexander - Thank you, I am thinking if `0` should be `negative` or `positive`.

Comment: I believe you first want to filter the group to remove any values of zero, as it is neither positive nor negative.  Then use `.gt(0)` to return an array of those that are positive and take the mean to get the percentage of non-zero values that are positive.  `lambda x: x[x.ne(0)].gt(0).mean() * 100`

Comment: @Alexander -Thank you.  I think if use `>0` or `<0` then `0` is not count , so first filter non zero is not necessary `x[x.ne(0)]`?  What do you think?

Comment: It will tell you the number of positive values out of your group, but because your group contains zeros, I think the percentage would be incorrect.  Try it with [0.7, 0.4, 0, -0.2].  The result should be 0.666 (2 positives out of three non-zero values).

Comment: BTW, this is from experience...  I've analyzed data with lots of zeros (which really should have been NaN values).  Filtering them out is both correct and also prevents upward bias in the case of 'bad' data.